# Is there an Email Protocol to Decline an Auto Response?

Tags: email, auto-responder

If my program is sending an email reminder to a double opt in list of 1000 people, I don't care about getting their individual auto responders.

Is there an email header (or any other mechanism), even if non-standard, that would inform gmail, hotmail, exchange, or other large email platforms, to not send the auto response?

Pseduocode Header ...

```
{"auto-respond":"false"}
```

Ideally the solution is not to send from "NO-REPLY@example.com" since I really do want people to reply if needed, I'm just trying to save all the extra email generated by the OOF auto replies.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is. You could do something with so basic text search though. Just create a filter on "out of office" in the message.

You could also look at sendgrid, they may offer something.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the SMTP protocol does not allow anything like this. Like Chris mentions, the best you could do, is write a filter, to automatically delete/remove these.

--Dave